# Magento 2 - Second level category has no head

Tags: magento2, category, catalog

I tried making a 3 layer category system as pictured below.
For the category "Liquid Spice Blends" everything works well, the layout gets loaded and everything.

[image]

But for the test element as shown below, the head doesn't get loaded, I haven't made an override layout for the catalog so that is not the problem.

[image]

This is the HTML it generated for the test page :

```
<html><head></head><body cz-shortcut-listen="true"><div id="layer-product-list"></div></body></html>
```

It uses the same template as the working liquid spice blends, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because there were no items added to the "test" category in this case. 
After adding them the layout started appearing.